# Issue with DatePeriod Class Output

Tags: php, datetime

I'm using `DatePeriod` to get date difference between two dates but it creates issue when I need to get data `Year` based format. Following is my work

```
$start_date = '2016-08-29 21:47:33';
$end_date = '2018-04-28 17:30:55';

function getDateRange($start_date, $end_date, $type, $format = 'Y-m-d')
{
    $period = new DatePeriod(
        new DateTime($start_date),
        new DateInterval("P1{$type}"),
        new DateTime($end_date)
    );

    $dates = [];

    foreach($period as $dt)
    {
        $dates[] = $dt->format("$format");
    }

    return $dates;
}

print_r(getDateRange($start_date, $end_date, 'Y', 'Y'));
```

According to my function it should return

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2016
    [1] => 2017
    [2] => 2018
)
```

But its been outputting only two of them

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2016
    [1] => 2017
)
```

If I'm using output format with `Month & Year` i.e. `M Y` with `interval` of `Month` then it works fine output for that

```
print_r(getDateRange($start_date, $end_date, 'M', 'M Y'));

Array
(
    [0] => Aug 2016
    [1] => Sep 2016
    [2] => Oct 2016
    [3] => Nov 2016
    [4] => Dec 2016
    [5] => Jan 2017
    [6] => Mar 2017
    [7] => Apr 2017
    [8] => May 2017
    [9] => Jun 2017
    [10] => Jul 2017
    [11] => Aug 2017
    [12] => Sep 2017
    [13] => Oct 2017
    [14] => Nov 2017
    [15] => Dec 2017
    [16] => Jan 2018
    [17] => Feb 2018
    [18] => Mar 2018
    [19] => Apr 2018
)
```

Comment: Mind blown......

Comment: Probably because the last period is not finished when its counting years so its actually 2 years and some months...

Comment: Agree with @Jessedegans

Comment: So the possible solution is I need to pass `end_date` as `2018-12-31` forcefully right @Jessedegans. Even I do believe within your coment

Comment: @devmyb i think rahul meshram gives the right answer ;)

Comment: But actually it should be answered by you @Jessedegans. Thanks for your quick response

Comment: @devmyb ah no problem im here for the help not for the points :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified changes as per documentation [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php#102629),

Here is the code,

```
function getDateRange($start_date, $end_date, $type, $format = 'Y-m-d')
{
    $start_date = date_create_from_format("Y-m-d H:i:s", $start_date);
    $end_date = date_create_from_format("Y-m-d H:i:s", $end_date);
    $endDateInt = new DateInterval( "P1Y" );
    $end_date->add( $endDateInt );
    $period = new DatePeriod(
        $start_date,
        new DateInterval("P1{$type}"),
        $end_date
    );
    $dates = [];
    
    foreach($period as $dt)
    {
        $dates[] = $dt->format("$format");
    }

    return $dates;
}
$start_date = '2016-08-29 21:47:33';
$end_date = '2018-04-28 17:30:55';
print_r(getDateRange($start_date, $end_date, 'Y', 'Y'));
```

Here is working [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/32c67d6791e6dceb25499c9f213dc4f410b90862).

Answer (score 2):

You can see the reason why in your second output. The last date goes only until April, and the first one is in August. So it's indeed not two full years, and your first result is correct. If you want to make it be the number of "years involved", without regard for *actual* difference, you could simulate this by setting the second date to the same day and month as the first one, if `$type` is Y:

```
<?php
$start_date = '2016-08-29 23:47:33';
$end_date = '2018-09-28 17:30:55';

function getDateRange($start_date, $end_date, $type, $format = 'Y-m-d')
{
    $start = new DateTime($start_date);
    $end = new DateTime($end_date);
    if ($type === "Y") {
        $start->setTime(0, 0, 0);
        $end->setDate($end->format("Y"), $start->format("m"), $start->format("d"));
        $end->setTime(0, 0, 1);
    }
    $period = new DatePeriod(
        $start,
        new DateInterval("P1{$type}"),
        $end
    );

    $dates = [];

    foreach($period as $dt)
    {
        $dates[] = $dt->format("$format");
    }

    return $dates;
}

print_r(getDateRange($start_date, $end_date, 'Y', 'Y'));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/tdIbq)